# Condições em JavaScript não funcionando

Tags: javascript, if

Estou fazendo um cálculo com as seguintes informações:

Estilo, experiência, altura e peso.

Com a altura e peso, eu pego o IMC do usuário e comparo com sua experiência.
Com o estilo, eu defino o tipo de prancha.

Primeiro, eu pego o estilo de prancha. Com o estilo de prancha "em mãos", eu comparo o IMC e a Experiência do usuário e exibo o resultado.

O problema é que, somente a opção "SURF" está funcionando. Quando eu escolho a opção "StandUP Paddle", ele não funciona.

Como resolver isso?

```js
function calcularIMC(){  
var estilo = document.getElementById("estilo").value; 
var experiencia = document.getElementById("experiencia").value; 
var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value; 
var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value; 
var imc = 0;  

 
   if(altura >0 && peso >0){
     imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    }
  
  
    if(estilo == "StandUp Paddle"){  

      if((experiencia>=3) && (imc<=29)){        
        alert("SUP SURF");                 
      } 
       else if((experiencia<=3)&&(imc>29)){  
          alert("FUNBOARD");                
        }
                 
     }
      else if(estilo == "Surf"){            
         if(imc<=25){          
          alert("PRANCHINHA");  
      }
      else{         
          alert("LONGBOARD");        
          }
     }
}
```

```html
<span>Estilo</span><br>
<select name="estilo" id="estilo" value="estilo" required>
   <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha seu estilo</option>
   <option>StandUp Paddle</option>
   <option>Surf</option>
</select><br><br>

<span>Experiência</span><br>
  <select name="experiencia" id="experiencia" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha sua experiência</option>
  <option value="0">sem experiência</option>
  <option value="1">menos de 1 mês</option>
  <option value="2">até 3 meses</option>
  <option value="3">até 6 meses</option>
  <option value="4">1 ano ou mais</option>
</select>  <br> <br>


<span>Altura</span><br>
<select name="altura" id="altura" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha sua altura</option>
  <option>1.60</option>
  <option>1.61</option>
  <option>1.62</option>
  <option>1.63</option>
  <option>1.64</option>
  <option>1.65</option>
  <option>1.66</option>
  <option>1.67</option>
  <option>1.68</option>
  <option>1.69</option>
  <option>1.70</option>
  <option>1.71</option>
  <option>1.72</option>
  <option>1.73</option>
  <option>1.74</option>
  <option>1.75</option>
  <option>1.76</option>
  <option>1.77</option>
  <option>1.78</option>
  <option>1.79</option>
  <option>1.80</option>
  <option>1.81</option>
  <option>1.82</option>
  <option>1.83</option>
  <option>1.84</option>
  <option>1.85</option>
  <option>1.86</option>
  <option>1.87</option>
  <option>1.88</option>
  <option>1.89</option>
  <option>1.90</option>
  <option>1.91</option>
  <option>1.92</option>
  <option>1.93</option>
  <option>1.94</option>
  <option>1.95</option>
  <option>1.96</option>
  <option>1.97</option>
  <option>1.98</option>
  <option>1.99</option>
  <option>2.00</option> 
</select><br><br>


<span>Peso</span><br>
<select name="peso" id="peso" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha seu peso</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>        
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
  <option>60</option>
  <option>61</option>
  <option>62</option>
  <option>63</option>
  <option>64</option>
  <option>65</option>
  <option>66</option>
  <option>67</option>
  <option>68</option>
  <option>69</option>
  <option>70</option>
  <option>71</option>
  <option>72</option>
  <option>73</option>
  <option>74</option>
  <option>75</option>
  <option>76</option>
  <option>77</option>
  <option>78</option>
  <option>79</option>
  <option>80</option>
  <option>81</option>
  <option>82</option>
  <option>83</option>
  <option>84</option>
  <option>85</option>
  <option>86</option>
  <option>87</option>
  <option>88</option>
  <option>89</option>
  <option>90</option>
  <option>91</option>
  <option>92</option>
  <option>93</option>
  <option>94</option>
  <option>95</option>
  <option>96</option>
  <option>97</option>
  <option>98</option>
  <option>99</option>
  <option>100</option>
</select><br><br>

    
 <button id="Enviar" onclick="calcularIMC();">Send</button>
```

Consegui através desta maneira:

```
if(estilo == "Surf"){            
   if((imc<=25) && (resultado == 5)){          
    alert("PRANCHINHA");  
}
else{         
    alert("LONGBOARD");        
    }
}    
else if(estilo == "SUP"){      
  if((experiencia >= 3) && (imc <=29)){
    alert("Sup Surf");
  } else{
    alert("FUNBOARD")
  }                       
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema.

Comment: Rode o Snippet escolhendo o estilo "StandUp Paddle"

Comment: Ainda não entendi qual é o problema. Se não explicar, vou continuar sem saber.

Comment: @bigown Atualizei a pergunta. Dá uma olhada pf

Comment: Não funciona é muito genérico, você tem que explicar o que deveria acontecer.

Comment: Dentro do `if(estilo == "StandUp Paddle")` você só testa `experiencia>=3` (até 6 meses). E se o usuário escolher uma experiência menor do que 3?

Comment: Pra mim está funcionando. Só não sei se está do jeito que deseja, não temos como adivinhar o jeito que quer.

Comment: @abfurlan Verdade. Inverti o simbolo.

Comment: @bigown Quando eu escolho a opção `StandUp Paddle` o alert não dispara. Este é o problema

Comment: Respondi o que consegui, senão for isso, aguardo a explicação do que o código deveria fazer. Ficar repetindo a mesma coisa sem explicar o que deveria fazer, não vai ajudar ninguém ajudar.

Comment: O objetivo do código é definir um tipo de prancha ideal para o usuário. De acordo com suas informações (estilo de prancha, tempo de experiência, altura e peso). Com a altura e o peso dele, eu calculo o IMC - Índice de Massa Corporal, assim eu tenho noção do estado de saúde do usuário. Com essa informação "em mãos", eu comparo com o tempo de experiência e estilo de prancha e dou o resultado

Comment: Eu votei pra fechar porque a última edição deixou claro que a pergunta não pode ser respondida por ninguém a não ser o próprio autor dela. Mesma a resposta colocada não funciona corretamente em qualquer definição a não ser que volte ter comportamento semelhante ao que o autor diz ser problema, ou seja, há situações em que nada é feito.

Comment: @LuizSantos A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Esta é uma forma que poderia resolver o problema, mas não posso garantir porque a pergunta não explica qual é o resultado desejado. Até houve uma edição que muda completamente o que deveria fazer. Tudo leva a crer que a edição deixou o código mais errado ainda, mas não tem como garantir. Depois houve outra edição colocando uma solução que certamente está errada e mesmo que fosse a certa ainda concluiríamos que só o AP poderia responder a pergunta.

Note que organizar o código ajuda entendê-lo.

```js
function calcularIMC() {  
    var estilo = document.getElementById("estilo").value; 
    var experiencia = document.getElementById("experiencia").value; 
    var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value; 
    var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value; 
    var imc = 0;  
    if (altura > 0 && peso > 0) {
        imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    }
    if (estilo == "StandUp Paddle") {  
        if (experiencia >=3) {   
            if (imc<=29) {   
                alert("SUP SURF");                 
            } else { 
                alert("FUNBOARD");                
            }
        } else { 
            alert("Alguma mensagem pra quem não tem experiência suficiente");
        }
    } else if (estilo == "Surf") {            
         if (imc <= 25) {          
             alert("PRANCHINHA");  
         } else {         
             alert("LONGBOARD");        
         }
    }
}
```

```html
<span>Estilo</span><br>
<select name="estilo" id="estilo" value="estilo" required>
   <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha seu estilo</option>
   <option>StandUp Paddle</option>
   <option>Surf</option>
</select><br><br>

<span>Experiência</span><br>
  <select name="experiencia" id="experiencia" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha sua experiência</option>
  <option value="0">sem experiência</option>
  <option value="1">menos de 1 mês</option>
  <option value="2">até 3 meses</option>
  <option value="3">até 6 meses</option>
  <option value="4">1 ano ou mais</option>
</select>  <br> <br>


<span>Altura</span><br>
<select name="altura" id="altura" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha sua altura</option>
  <option>1.60</option>
  <option>1.61</option>
  <option>1.62</option>
  <option>1.63</option>
  <option>1.64</option>
  <option>1.65</option>
  <option>1.66</option>
  <option>1.67</option>
  <option>1.68</option>
  <option>1.69</option>
  <option>1.70</option>
  <option>1.71</option>
  <option>1.72</option>
  <option>1.73</option>
  <option>1.74</option>
  <option>1.75</option>
  <option>1.76</option>
  <option>1.77</option>
  <option>1.78</option>
  <option>1.79</option>
  <option>1.80</option>
  <option>1.81</option>
  <option>1.82</option>
  <option>1.83</option>
  <option>1.84</option>
  <option>1.85</option>
  <option>1.86</option>
  <option>1.87</option>
  <option>1.88</option>
  <option>1.89</option>
  <option>1.90</option>
  <option>1.91</option>
  <option>1.92</option>
  <option>1.93</option>
  <option>1.94</option>
  <option>1.95</option>
  <option>1.96</option>
  <option>1.97</option>
  <option>1.98</option>
  <option>1.99</option>
  <option>2.00</option> 
</select><br><br>


<span>Peso</span><br>
<select name="peso" id="peso" required>
  <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha seu peso</option>
  <option>50</option>
  <option>51</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>53</option>        
  <option>54</option>
  <option>55</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>57</option>
  <option>58</option>
  <option>59</option>
  <option>60</option>
  <option>61</option>
  <option>62</option>
  <option>63</option>
  <option>64</option>
  <option>65</option>
  <option>66</option>
  <option>67</option>
  <option>68</option>
  <option>69</option>
  <option>70</option>
  <option>71</option>
  <option>72</option>
  <option>73</option>
  <option>74</option>
  <option>75</option>
  <option>76</option>
  <option>77</option>
  <option>78</option>
  <option>79</option>
  <option>80</option>
  <option>81</option>
  <option>82</option>
  <option>83</option>
  <option>84</option>
  <option>85</option>
  <option>86</option>
  <option>87</option>
  <option>88</option>
  <option>89</option>
  <option>90</option>
  <option>91</option>
  <option>92</option>
  <option>93</option>
  <option>94</option>
  <option>95</option>
  <option>96</option>
  <option>97</option>
  <option>98</option>
  <option>99</option>
  <option>100</option>
</select><br><br>

    
 <button id="Enviar" onclick="calcularIMC();">Send</button>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Bmi.js).

Comment: Ínves destes três `if`. Eu não poderia fazer de uma forma direta `if((experiencia>= 3) && (imc<= 29))` ?

Comment: Depende, você ainda não disse o que você deseja. Tem caso que pode, tem caso que não pode.

Comment: O objetivo do código é definir um tipo de prancha ideal para o usuário. De acordo com suas informações (estilo de prancha, tempo de experiência, altura e peso). Com a altura e o peso dele, eu calculo o IMC - Índice de Massa Corporal, assim eu tenho noção do estado de saúde do usuário. Com essa informação "em mãos", eu comparo com o tempo de experiência e estilo de prancha e dou o resultado

Comment: `SE` o estilo de prancha for `STANDUP PADDLE`... A `experiencia` for maior ou igual a `6 meses` e o IMC dele for `<=29`, `alert("SUP SURF");

Comment: Estou fazendo isso de uma forma direta `if((experiencia>= 3) && (imc<= 29))` e não está pegando. Este é meu problema

Comment: Não tenho como ajudar mais que isso sem dar mais detalhes. Você pode testar na resposta e ver que funciona. Se não funciona do jeito que deseja eu não tenho o que fazer, você não explica de uma forma que dê para ajudar. Seu problema provavelmente não é código, é não saber o que deseja fazer, e aí ninguém consegue te ajudar.

Comment: Eu fiz de uma forma diferente, mas consegui o que queria. Obrigado pela disposição em ajudar! Coloquei o código na pergunta.